# Error when calling carousel.to() in Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

```
// Init carousel
let carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(document.querySelector('#carouselMenu'), {
        interval: 0,
        wrap: false
});

// <SNIP>

// Jump to page with index 1
carousel.to("1");
```

Error:

[image: Carousel Error]

If don't use JS and add HTML attribute for button `data-bs-slide-to="1"`, then jumping is work

Comment: Does `document.querySelector('#carouselMenu')` return the expected element?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: Well, from what I can see you've tagged Bootstrap 4 but you're using Bootstrap 5 code for the carousel. Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: tag with version 5 i couldn't find. I'm using version 5

Answer (score 0):

I would split it out like the documentation has it.  Also I wouldnt initialize with a 0 time interval, the default is 5000 so I would start either there or 2000 to verify its not the 0 causing the issue.  Lastly the documentation says the the to method is 0 based similar to an array, so I would assume you would want to pass a value and not a string so I would remove the ""

```
var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#carouselMenu')
var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel, {
        interval: 2000,
        wrap: false
});

// <SNIP>

// Jump to page with index 1
carousel.to(1);
```